# Devpi-server. redirect to additional server

Tags: python, server, devpi, pypiserver

How and where I can define addional redirect server for Devpi-server ? Primary is pypi.python.org by default. I need additional. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With devpi version 3.0 you can create "mirror" indexes: http://doc.devpi.net/latest/userman/devpi_indices.html#mirror-index

So I guess you could create one index that mirror PyPI and another that mirrors the other server. And then create a index that inherits both of those indexes.